# How to modify the default row-height of apex:pageblocktable in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, apex

I am new to Salesforce VF pages. I have a dynamically binded pageBlockTable in my Visualforce page. Now I am struggling to reduce its default row-height. Any help is really appreciated.

I have found a lot of examples like resizing columns in google, but not for rows. Also, I have tried adding line-height in rowclasses CSS style, but it is of no help.

CSS style:

```
.headerfontstyle
        {
            font-size:12px !important;
        } 
        .rowdatastyle
        {
            color:#333;
            font-size:11px !important;
        } 
        .Tokenfontstyle
        {
             color:#333;
            font-size:12px !important;
        } 
        .odd { 
        background-color: #E8E8E8 !important;
       line-height: 5px !important;

      }
    .even {
        background-color: #FCF7F7 !important;
        line-height: 5px !important;

    }
```

VF page code:

```
<apex:pageblock id="DetailsBlock">
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstDet}" var="oDet"   styleclass="table table-striped table-hover" id="sysTable" rowClasses="even,odd">

<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 20%;height:4%"  ><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Name </font></apex:facet> 
<font class="rowdatastyle"> {!oDet.Name} </font>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 10%;height:4%"  ><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Mfg</font></apex:facet> 
<font class="rowdatastyle" >  {!oDet.Manufacturer}</font>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 6%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Type</font></apex:facet> 
<font class="rowdatastyle" > {!oDet.ComponentType} </font>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 12%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Allocated</font></apex:facet>  
<font class="rowdatastyle"> {!oDet.Allocated} </font>
</apex:column>                                                        
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 10%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >Used</font></apex:facet>  
<font class="rowdatastyle"> {!oDet.Used} </font>
</apex:column>                                                        
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" style="width: 30%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle" >OS Version</font></apex:facet>  
<font class="rowdatastyle">{!oDet.OS} </font>
</apex:column>  
<apex:column headerClass="TableTitle" id="hiddenblock" style="width: 10%;height:4%"><apex:facet name="header"><font class="headerfontstyle">Action</font></apex:facet> 
<div class="btn-group">
<a class="btn btn-transparent-grey dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
<i class="fa fa-cog"></i> <span class="caret"></span>
</a>        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-dark pull-right">
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href=" ">View</a> </li>
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href=" ">Create</a></li>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  </ul>   
</div>  

</apex:column>           
</apex:pageblockTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove all styles within `<apex:column>` and it should just work. Keep below lines:

```
.odd { 
    background-color: #E8E8E8 !important;
    line-height: 5px !important;
}
.even {
    background-color: #FCF7F7 !important;
    line-height: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful. :-)